# output the Variables with score > mean score are selected in python

Tags: python, arrays

If I had two array each variable associated with its given score:

1. first array consists of the following (variables,score):

- F12 ------>   0.769327
- F8  ------>  0.932702
- F6  ------> 0.980982
- F9  ------> 0.998438
- F7  ------>  0.999610
- F2  ------>  1.000000
- F3  ------>  1.000000
- F1  ------>  1.000000
- F11 ------>  1.000000
- F4  ------> 1.000000
- F10 ------> 1.000000
- F5  ------> 1.000000

2. the second array is the following (variables,score):

- F2  ------>   0.179329
- F3  ------>  0.148576
- F1  ------>  0.179842
- F11 ------>  0.217283
- F4  ------>  0.184893
- F6  ------>  0.150987
- F10 ------>   0.267837
- F9  ------>   0.121113
- F5  ------>   0.126617
- F7  ------>    0.112994
- F12 ------>   0.900000
- F8  ------>   0.100000

3. and I want to combine these two array into one array then find the mean score calculation associated with

- F2, F3, F1, F11, F4, F6, F10, F9, F5, F7, F12, F8

4. finally, output the Variables with score > mean score are selected. all code in python.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and the specific issues encountered; notice that SO is not a code writing service. Also, question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `database` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `arrays` with the type of objects that you have. [Arrays are homogeneous](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) objects, assuming you use NumPy.

For your purpose you should use `lists`, they can be heterogeneous:

```
lst1 = [['F12', 0.769327], ['F8', 0.932702], ['F6', 0.980982],
        ['F9', 0.998438], ['F7', 0.999610], ['F2', 1.000000],
        ['F3', 1.000000], ['F1', 1.000000], ['F11', 1.000000],
        ['F4', 1.000000], ['F10', 1.000000], ['F5', 1.000000]]

lst2 = [['F2', 0.179329], ['F3', 0.148576], ['F1', 0.179842],
        ['F11', 0.217283], ['F4', 0.184893], ['F6', 0.150987],
        ['F10', 0.267837], ['F9', 0.121113], ['F5', 0.126617],
        ['F7', 0.112994], ['F12', 0.900000], ['F8', 0.100000]]
```

To concatenate two lists you can use the operator `+`:

```
lst3 = lst1 + lst2
```

Then you can iterate through the list to calculate the mean and select variables that meet your condition:

```
lst3_mean = 0

for i in lst3:
    lst3_mean += i[1]
lst3_mean = lst3_mean / len(lst3)

result = []
for i in lst3:
    if i[1] > lst3_mean and i[0] not in result:
        result.append(i[0])
print(result)
```

Comment: thanks peter a lot, really I do much similar your solution except that I want to compare the list1 values with 1, if value in list1 >= output the variables associated with this value so i did the following: selected _variable = np.all(np.asarray(list1) >= 1  
print (selected _variable)but it didn't work.

Comment: sorry, peter. but i gave a wrong calculated mean. i.e the lst_mean should =  0.5737738699887709
 but it gave  0.005737738699887709
where is the missing solution, plz

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate the mean like that:

```py
mean = np.sum(np.concatenate((arr1[:,1], arr2[:,1])))/12
```

and then filter the ones that are greater then the mean like that:

```py
res = arr1[arr1 > mean]
```